# You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Error Showing when post data from API

```
You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.
```

My written Code is:

```
serializerdata = serializers.CreateSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializerdata.is_valid():
    user_id = serializerdata.data.get('user_id')
    if user_id==2:
        serializerdata.save(i_created_by=request.user)
        return JsonResponse({"message": "success"}) 
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "user invalid"})    
else:
    return JsonResponse({"message": "error"})
```

Comment: How does the `request.data` looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you can not access the `serializer.data` and then call `save()`.

You should instead user `validated_data`:

```
user_id = serializerdata.validated_data.get('user_id')
```

Comment: I checked it's working. But can you explain the reason.

Comment: I think it's because `data` is the original input to the serializer, while `validated_data` is the actual *validated* input. If you somehow access or modify `data`, after validating the serializer, you can't be certain about what the result of `serializer.save()` is going to be.

Comment: @NicoGriffioen Really? Is that somewhere in the official DRF documentation? Any reference would be highly appreciated. Or a link to the relevant DRF source.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the docs about this behavior, because the docs only describe how to use serializers, and they don't go too much in-depth on the how-and-why of all scenario's.

The only thing I can point to is [the code itself](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/98e56e0327596db352b35fa3b3dc8355dc9bd030/rest_framework/serializers.py#L191)

From the implementation itself, it's clear that ```self.data``` and ```self.save()``` are not meant to be used together, but it's not clear why not.

Comment: The docs do say [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/): 
"Serializers also provide deserialization, allowing parsed data to be converted back into complex types, after first validating the incoming data."

This constraint forces you to do any additional logic on the validated_data, which forces you to validate first.

Answer (score 8):

**Take care that in your debugger watch there is no *serializer.data* listed**.
It will read out the data before *serializer.save()* is invoked and lead to this confusing behaviour. Took me at least an hour to figure it out.

Comment: thank you. that was my problem